# More efficient way to do multiple date calculations in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a frame that includes one date column (which is indeed of class Date) and a number column (class Numeric)

```
       first       last       date number
1   Reynalda     Morley 1953-07-03      9
2     Annice     Meador 1954-10-29     38
3       Jude    Pertuit 1956-08-23     49
4    Viviana      Dance 1979-11-07     32
5    Lavonda      Babst 1982-02-06     17
6    Rachele Eisenhower 1985-11-12     27
7     Ericka     Roesch 1987-05-02     22
8   Giovanni      Bemis 1988-06-23     33
9      Ferne       Mone 2005-12-21     36
10 Anjanette   Eppinger 2010-01-03      4
```

I want to walk through each year and get the cumulative total to date and the average for the year. Roughly I want to end up with a result frame like:

```
    year    total.to.date   average.this.year
1   2001    128     32
2   2002    128     0
3   2003    145     17
4   2004    227     27.3333333333333
5   2005    267     20
```

I know I can use a whole series of subsets for each calculation, but I also know that if I were smarter about ... maybe tapply? ... I could just churn it out. Do I need to add a library to work with dates like this?

Answer (score 1):

It works with the `by` function.

```
dat <- read.table(text="first       last       date number
1   Reynalda     Morley 1953-07-03      9
2     Annice     Meador 1954-10-29     38
3       Jude    Pertuit 1956-08-23     49
4    Viviana      Dance 1979-11-07     32
5    Lavonda      Babst 1982-02-06     17
6    Rachele Eisenhower 1985-11-12     27
7     Ericka     Roesch 1987-05-02     22
8   Giovanni      Bemis 1988-06-23     33
9      Ferne       Mone 2005-12-21     36
10 Anjanette   Eppinger 2010-01-03      4", header = TRUE)

dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date)
```

These commands generate the data. The cumulative total is calculated with the `cumsum` function:

```
result <- with(dat, by(number, format(date,"%Y"), function(x) c(mean(x),sum(x))))
result <- data.frame(names(result), do.call(rbind, result))
result <- setNames(cbind(result[-3], cumsum(result[3])),
                   c("year", "average.this.year", "total.to.date"))
```

The `result`:

```
   year average.this.year total.to.date
1  1953                 9             9
2  1954                38            47
3  1956                49            96
4  1979                32           128
5  1982                17           145
6  1985                27           172
7  1987                22           194
8  1988                33           227
9  2005                36           263
10 2010                 4           267
```